# how to check firebase cloud firestore size in a project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

how to check firebase cloud firestore size in a project?
according to firebase the free plan gives you 1GB for firebase cloud firestore,  i already create some collections with documents inside, but where can i check the total size i am using?

i already check some statistics in firebase console but i can only see the numbers of reads and writes.
[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can check your Cloud Firestore size or **Cloud Firestore stored data** in Google Cloud [App Engine Quotas page](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails). You can go direct to Google Cloud using the [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails) because when you create a Firebase project, you're also creating a project in the Google Cloud.

Inside the App Engine Quotas page you can see also the other Cloud Firestore usage information including reads, writes, index writes, deletes, and network egress.

**Example images:**

[image: Cloud Firestore Usage]

#### UPDATE:

You can check your usage up to last 30 days in [Firestore Database > Usage](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/firestore/usage)

Comment: This only shows usage per day. Is there a way to see total usage?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can’t check the usage of bytes stored per month in Firestore. Only per day.

Usage per day can be checked in the app engine

[image: google cloud]

It’s confusing because you don’t know how much data you have stored in total in Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

I verified it with Google support and got the following:

1. Through the billing report, you can see the storage size.
   [image]
2. Using this command (change the **project_name**, and in case the **databaseId** is different from 'default' add it as well:

```js
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token) -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'{"gqlQuery": {"queryString": "SELECT * FROM __Stat_Total__"}, "databaseId": ""}' "https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/project_name:runQuery"
```

This will output a Json and size can be taken from here:

{"batch": {"entityResults": [ {"entity": {"properties": {"bytes": {"integerValue": "xxxx"} } } } ] } }

```
"properties": {
      ...
        "bytes": {
          "integerValue": "1468853491845"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also these stats
[image: screenshot]

in `Project Overview > Usage and billing` (gear icon, top left)

Answer (score -2):

1. Go to the [Firestore Usage tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/firestore/usage)
2. Click "View in Usage and Billing" (bottom right)
   [image]
3. This will show a summary of usage including total bytes stored, bandwidth, reads, writes, and deletes.
   [image]

Comment: This shows bytes stored for Cloud Storage, not Firestore